# How to declare POINT structure to get rid of Code Analysis error?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, pinvoke, code-analysis

I have a problem with declaration of `POINT` structure, which I use in conjunction with Windows functions `WindowFromPoint` and `GetCursorPos`. When the structure has `int` fields then Code Analysis reports error: CA1901:PInvokeDeclarationsShouldBePortable (CA1901    P/Invoke declarations should be portable. As it is declared in your code, parameter 'point' of P/Invoke `NativeMethods.WindowFromPoint(NativeMethods.POINTAPI)` will be 8 bytes wide on 32-bit platforms.) When I change type of the fields to `Int16` the error is not returned, but the function `GetCursorPos` stops working.

I run the app on Windows 8.1 x64. The signatures of the functions and the structure are as follows:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(POINTAPI point);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINTAPI
{
    internal int x;
    internal int y;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern int GetCursorPos(out POINTAPI lpPoint);
```

Below is a summary of what I've tried to do:

1. X and y declared as `int` (as above) --- the app works correctly, Code Analysis shows the error.
2. X and y declared as `Int16` --- when the function `GetCursorPos` is invoked the app crashes, Code Analysis returns no error.
3. X and y declared as `Int32` --- the app works correctly, Code Analysis shows the error.
4. X and y declared as `Int64` --- the function `WindowFromPoint` returns unexpected result, Code Analysis shows the error.

Does anybody know how to get the app working without the Code Analysis error (which currently has to be suppressed)?

Comment: If you explicitly marshal the struct members as `UnmanagedType.I4` does the analysis warning go away?

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182284.aspx) says _Breaking - If the P/Invoke is visible outside the assembly. Non Breaking - If the P/Invoke is not visible outside the assembly._  So can you make `POINTAPI` internal or private?

Comment: @juharr Since both `x` and `y` are `internal`, I suspect the answer is "yes".

Comment: @theB When the struct members are marshaled as UnmanagedType.I4 the warning is still reported.

Comment: @juharr When `POINTAPI` is `internal` the warning does not go away.

Comment: @J.Carter What about `private`.  I'm just curious what the _visible outside the assembly_ exactly means then.

Comment: @juharr With `private` visibility the warning is the same like with `internal`. I think that _visible outside the assembly_ rather concerns functions. I got rid of a few warnings changing function visibility from `public` to `internal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `Int16` and `Int64` fail because they are the wrong type. The native declaration uses `LONG` which is signed 32 bit. So `int` or `Int32` are both correct.

The declaration of the struct in your question is precisely how I would declare this. But you could just as well use `Int32` if you prefer.

However, `WindowFromPoint` is unusual. It accepts `POINT` rather than `POINT*` which is somewhat odd. I suspect that the Microsoft engineers got this wrong a long time ago and cannot change it now for obvious reasons.

It looks like this unusual function declaration for `WindowFromPoint` is in fact what is confusing the code analysis tool. What counts though is that your code works. So, use the correct code (as found in your code in this question), and suppress the bogus code analysis warnings.